# How to implement C2DM in android properly?

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

Hi I am very new to android. I would like to implement push notification for my application. I
tried by many ways. But till now I didn't get c2dm properly. Each samples are done in different ways. So,I totally confused. Can any body tell me the concrete way to implement C2DM? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these links:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html